# Sum in magic square isnt working properly for size> 37

Tags: arrays, c, sum, magic-square

I'm first year csd student I have an assignment where I need to check whether  a square is a magic square and print "Yes" or "No" for each row (including diagonals) and column that  meets the sum of the requirement magic square , if each number on it is unique and in the end if it is magic.

For example it should like this:

[Input of the size of the square + the numbers we put in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB5SN.png)

[the required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH0jU.png)

My problem is that my algorithm works for the test that  are from numbers (size of square) 1 to 9.Then the test inputs go to 37+. For the tests that the size of box is 37+ the sum of each row and column does not add correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXN 100
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc==2 || argc==3){ 
        if ( strcmp("-check",argv[1])==0){
            int p=0;
            int i;
            int j;
            int sum;
            int sum2;
            int N;
            char ch[]="YES";
            char unique[]="YES";
            int pin1[MAXN];
            scanf("%d", &N);
            int pin[MAXN][MAXN];
            for (i=0; i<N;i++){
                for (j=0; j<N;j++){
                    scanf ("%d",&pin[i][j]);
                     pin1[i*N+j]=pin[i][j];
                }
            }
            i=0;
            if (pin1[i]>N*N){
                strcpy(unique, "NO");
                    }
            for (i=0;i<N*N;i++){
                    for (j=i+1;j<N*N;j++){
                        if (pin1[i]==pin1[j] || pin1[i]>N*N){
                        strcpy(unique, "NO");
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i=0;i<N;i++){
                sum=0;
                strcpy(ch, "YES");
                for (j=0;j<N;j++){
                    sum=sum+pin[i][j];
                }
                if (sum!=(N*(N*N+1)/2)){
                    strcpy(ch, "NO");
                    p=1;
                }  
                printf("ROW %d %s\n",i+1,ch);  
            }
            for (j=0;j<N;j++){
                sum=0;
               strcpy(ch, "YES");
                for (i=0;i<N;i++){
                    sum=sum+pin[i][j];
                }
                if (sum!=(N*(N*N+1)/2)){
                    strcpy(ch, "NO");
                     p=1;
                }
                printf("COLUMN %d %s\n",j+1,ch);
            }
            sum=0;
            sum2=0;
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            for (i=0;i<N;i++){
                sum=sum+pin[i][i];
                sum2=sum2+pin[N-1-i][i];
            }
            if (sum!=(N*(N*N+1)/2)){
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
                p=1;
            }
            printf("DIAG1 %s\n",ch);
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            if (sum2!=(N*(N*N+1)/2)){
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
                p=1;
            }
            printf("DIAG2 %s\n",ch);
            printf("UNIQUE %s\n",unique);
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            if (p==1){
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
            }
            printf("MAGIC %s\n",ch);
        }
        else if ( strcmp("-create",argv[1])==0){
            int N=atoi(argv[2]);
            int pin[MAXN][MAXN];
            int row=N-1;
            int col=N/2;
            for (int i=1;i<=N*N;i++){
                int tempr=row;
                int tempc=col;
                pin[row][col]=i;
                row++;
                col++;
                if (row==N){
                    row=0;
                }
                if (col==N){
                    col=0;
                }
                if ((pin[row][col]>=1) & (pin[row][col]<=N*N)){
                    row=tempr-1;
                    col=tempc;
                } 
            }
            printf("%d\n",N);
            for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
                    for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                        printf("%d ",pin[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Such action cannot be done");
        }
    }
    else if (argc>3){
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("At least one argument expected.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
one of the inputs that fail:
37
667 706 745 784 823 862 901 940 979 1018 1057 1096 1135 1174 1213 1252 1291 1330 1369 2 41 80 119 158 197 236 275 314 353 392 431 470 509 548 587 626 665 
666 668 707 746 785 824 863 902 941 980 1019 1058 1097 1136 1175 1214 1253 1292 1331 1333 3 42 81 120 159 198 237 276 315 354 393 432 471 510 549 588 627 
628 630 669 708 747 786 825 864 903 942 981 1020 1059 1098 1137 1176 1215 1254 1293 1332 1334 4 43 82 121 160 199 238 277 316 355 394 433 472 511 550 589 
590 629 631 670 709 748 787 826 865 904 943 982 1021 1060 1099 1138 1177 1216 1255 1294 1296 1335 5 44 83 122 161 200 239 278 317 356 395 434 473 512 551 
552 591 593 632 671 710 749 788 827 866 905 944 983 1022 1061 1100 1139 1178 1217 1256 1295 1297 1336 6 45 84 123 162 201 240 279 318 357 396 435 474 513 
514 553 592 594 633 672 711 750 789 828 867 906 945 984 1023 1062 1101 1140 1179 1218 1257 1259 1298 1337 7 46 85 124 163 202 241 280 319 358 397 436 475 
476 515 554 556 595 634 673 712 751 790 829 868 907 946 985 1024 1063 1102 1141 1180 1219 1258 1260 1299 1338 8 47 86 125 164 203 242 281 320 359 398 437 
438 477 516 555 557 596 635 674 713 752 791 830 869 908 947 986 1025 1064 1103 1142 1181 1220 1222 1261 1300 1339 9 48 87 126 165 204 243 282 321 360 399 
400 439 478 517 519 558 597 636 675 714 753 792 831 870 909 948 987 1026 1065 1104 1143 1182 1221 1223 1262 1301 1340 10 49 88 127 166 205 244 283 322 361 
362 401 440 479 518 520 559 598 637 676 715 754 793 832 871 910 949 988 1027 1066 1105 1144 1183 1185 1224 1263 1302 1341 11 50 89 128 167 206 245 284 323 
324 363 402 441 480 482 521 560 599 638 677 716 755 794 833 872 911 950 989 1028 1067 1106 1145 1184 1186 1225 1264 1303 1342 12 51 90 129 168 207 246 285 
286 325 364 403 442 481 483 522 561 600 639 678 717 756 795 834 873 912 951 990 1029 1068 1107 1146 1148 1187 1226 1265 1304 1343 13 52 91 130 169 208 247 
248 287 326 365 404 443 445 484 523 562 601 640 679 718 757 796 835 874 913 952 991 1030 1069 1108 1147 1149 1188 1227 1266 1305 1344 14 53 92 131 170 209 
210 249 288 327 366 405 444 446 485 524 563 602 641 680 719 758 797 836 875 914 953 992 1031 1070 1109 1111 1150 1189 1228 1267 1306 1345 15 54 93 132 171 
172 211 250 289 328 367 406 408 447 486 525 564 603 642 681 720 759 798 837 876 915 954 993 1032 1071 1110 1112 1151 1190 1229 1268 1307 1346 16 55 94 133 
134 173 212 251 290 329 368 407 409 448 487 526 565 604 643 682 721 760 799 838 877 916 955 994 1033 1072 1074 1113 1152 1191 1230 1269 1308 1347 17 56 95 
96 135 174 213 252 291 330 369 371 410 449 488 527 566 605 644 683 722 761 800 839 878 917 956 995 1034 1073 1075 1114 1153 1192 1231 1270 1309 1348 18 57 
58 97 136 175 214 253 292 331 370 372 411 450 489 528 567 606 645 684 723 762 801 840 879 918 957 996 1035 1037 1076 1115 1154 1193 1232 1271 1310 1349 19 
20 59 98 137 176 215 254 293 332 334 373 412 451 490 529 568 607 646 685 724 763 802 841 880 919 958 997 1036 1038 1077 1116 1155 1194 1233 1272 1311 1350 
1351 21 60 99 138 177 216 255 294 333 335 374 413 452 491 530 569 608 647 686 725 764 803 842 881 920 959 998 1000 1039 1078 1117 1156 1195 1234 1273 1312 
1313 1352 22 61 100 139 178 217 256 295 297 336 375 414 453 492 531 570 609 648 687 726 765 804 843 882 921 960 999 1001 1040 1079 1118 1157 1196 1235 1274 
1275 1314 1353 23 62 101 140 179 218 257 296 298 337 376 415 454 493 532 571 610 649 688 727 766 805 844 883 922 961 963 1002 1041 1080 1119 1158 1197 1236 
1237 1276 1315 1354 24 63 102 141 180 219 258 260 299 338 377 416 455 494 533 572 611 650 689 728 767 806 845 884 923 962 964 1003 1042 1081 1120 1159 1198 
1199 1238 1277 1316 1355 25 64 103 142 181 220 259 261 300 339 378 417 456 495 534 573 612 651 690 729 768 807 846 885 924 926 965 1004 1043 1082 1121 1160 
1161 1200 1239 1278 1317 1356 26 65 104 143 182 221 223 262 301 340 379 418 457 496 535 574 613 652 691 730 769 808 847 886 925 927 966 1005 1044 1083 1122 
1123 1162 1201 1240 1279 1318 1357 27 66 105 144 183 222 224 263 302 341 380 419 458 497 536 575 614 653 692 731 770 809 848 887 889 928 967 1006 1045 1084 
1085 1124 1163 1202 1241 1280 1319 1358 28 67 106 145 184 186 225 264 303 342 381 420 459 498 537 576 615 654 693 732 771 810 849 888 890 929 968 1007 1046 
1047 1086 1125 1164 1203 1242 1281 1320 1359 29 68 107 146 185 187 226 265 304 343 382 421 460 499 538 577 616 655 694 733 772 811 850 852 891 930 969 1008 
1009 1048 1087 1126 1165 1204 1243 1282 1321 1360 30 69 108 147 149 188 227 266 305 344 383 422 461 500 539 578 617 656 695 734 773 812 851 853 892 931 970 
971 1010 1049 1088 1127 1166 1205 1244 1283 1322 1361 31 70 109 148 150 189 228 267 306 345 384 423 462 501 540 579 618 657 696 735 774 813 815 854 893 932 
933 972 1011 1050 1089 1128 1167 1206 1245 1284 1323 1362 32 71 110 112 151 190 229 268 307 346 385 424 463 502 541 580 619 658 697 736 775 814 816 855 894 
895 934 973 1012 1051 1090 1129 1168 1207 1246 1285 1324 1363 33 72 111 113 152 191 230 269 308 347 386 425 464 503 542 581 620 659 698 737 776 778 817 856 
857 896 935 974 1013 1052 1091 1130 1169 1208 1247 1286 1325 1364 34 73 75 114 153 192 231 270 309 348 387 426 465 504 543 582 621 660 699 738 777 779 818 
819 858 897 936 975 1014 1053 1092 1131 1170 1209 1248 1287 1326 1365 35 74 76 115 154 193 232 271 310 349 388 427 466 505 544 583 622 661 700 739 741 780 
781 820 859 898 937 976 1015 1054 1093 1132 1171 1210 1249 1288 1327 1366 36 38 77 116 155 194 233 272 311 350 389 428 467 506 545 584 623 662 701 740 742 
743 782 821 860 899 938 977 1016 1055 1094 1133 1172 1211 1250 1289 1328 1367 37 39 78 117 156 195 234 273 312 351 390 429 468 507 546 585 624 663 702 704 
705 744 783 822 861 900 939 978 1017 1056 1095 1134 1173 1212 1251 1290 1329 1368 1 40 79 118 157 196 235 274 313 352 391 430 469 508 547 586 625 664 703
```

```
inputs that work:
1)
1
1
2)
3
2 7 6
9 5 1
4 3 8
3)
4
16 3 2 13
5 10 11 8
9 6 7 12
4 15 14 1
4)
5
11 18 25 2 9 
10 12 19 21 3 
4 6 13 20 22 
23 5 7 14 16 
17 24 1 8 15 
5)
7
22 31 40 49 2 11 20 
21 23 32 41 43 3 12 
13 15 24 33 42 44 4 
5 14 16 25 34 36 45 
46 6 8 17 26 35 37 
38 47 7 9 18 27 29 
30 39 48 1 10 19 28 
6)
9
37 48 59 70 81 2 13 24 35 
36 38 49 60 71 73 3 14 25 
26 28 39 50 61 72 74 4 15 
16 27 29 40 51 62 64 75 5 
6 17 19 30 41 52 63 65 76 
77 7 18 20 31 42 53 55 66 
67 78 8 10 21 32 43 54 56 
57 68 79 9 11 22 33 44 46 
47 58 69 80 1 12 23 34 45
```

This is my code for the algorithm explained above and the problem is on sum. pin[][] is the array with the square inputs in it and pin1[] is the array i made from pin to check if it has unique numbers or not. Your help will be greatly appreciated (I haven't included main and etc because the assignment asks for 2 things to check if a square is magic and to create one using arguments, I have included only the stuff I have done for the check process. MAXN is defined 100

Comment: the expected sum for a square that is 37x37 is 25345 for each row and column. However i printed the sum for each row to see the result and its different for each one.
for example this is some of the output of  the said square that should has a sum of 25345
row sum is  25763  ROW 1 NO
row sum is  24775  ROW 2 NO
row sum is  25193  ROW 3 NO
row sum is  25611  ROW 4 NO
row sum is  24623  ROW 5 NO
row sum is  25041  ROW 6 NO
row sum is  25459  ROW 7 NO
row sum is  25840  ROW 8 NO
as you can see it has different sum for each row when this should not happen

Comment: Please edit your question and post the input that fails (e.g. `37`) in a separate code block here. Do _not_ post as an _image_. And, post your _entire_ program _with_ `#include` and `main`. The fragment you did post is close, but we'd like to download the program, compile it without change and run it on our systems [if necessary]. I downloaded and cleaned up the program, added the input, and ran it. This is more work than most responders will be willing to do. It appears to produce the correct/expected output. So, what is the input that fails?

Comment: i did as you asked i hope now its more clear.

Comment: `pin1` should have been defined as `int pin1[MAXN*MAXN];`, **not** `int pin1[MAXN];`

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. At first I thought that `sum` et. al. was overflowing an `int` [and needed to be `long long`] but that's not the case
2. The `pin` array is [probably] too big to fit on the stack -- needs to be global scope.
3. The `pin1` array is `int pin1[MAXN];` but is accessed via (e.g.) `pin1[i * N + j]` so it needs to be `pin1[MAXN * MAXN];`. And, should also be global scope.

There were intermittant segfaults, so moving to global scope fixed those.

---

Here is the corrected code. Because I needed to run the program under `gdb`, I hacked in an `fopen` call and changed the `scanf` to be `fscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXN 100

#define SCAN(_sym) \
    fscanf(fin,"%d",&_sym)

#ifndef INPUT
#define INPUT   "inp37.txt"
#endif

#if 1
typedef int TYPE;
#else
typedef long long TYPE;
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: these are too large to be function scoped and won't fit on the
// stack
#if 1
int pin[MAXN][MAXN];
int pin1[MAXN * MAXN];
#endif

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// NOTE/FIX: hack for gdb/debug
#if 1
    FILE *fin = fopen(INPUT,"r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        perror(INPUT);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    if (argc == 2 || argc == 3) {
        if (strcmp("-check", argv[1]) == 0) {
            int p = 0;
            int i;
            int j;
            TYPE sum;
            TYPE sum2;
            int N;
            char ch[] = "YES";
            char unique[] = "YES";
// NOTE/BUG: wrong/insufficient dimension
#if 0
            int pin1[MAXN];
#endif

#if 0
            scanf("%d", &N);
#else
            SCAN(N);
            TYPE N2 = N * N;
            TYPE NGOOD = N;
            NGOOD = (NGOOD * (NGOOD * NGOOD + 1) / 2);
#endif
// NOTE/BUG: too large for stack variable
#if 0
            int pin[MAXN][MAXN];
#endif

            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
#if 0
                    scanf("%d", &pin[i][j]);
#else
                    SCAN(pin[i][j]);
#endif
                    pin1[i * N + j] = pin[i][j];
                }
            }
            i = 0;
            if (pin1[i] > N2) {
                strcpy(unique, "NO");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < N2; i++) {
                for (j = i + 1; j < N2; j++) {
                    if (pin1[i] == pin1[j] || pin1[i] > N2) {
                        strcpy(unique, "NO");
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                sum = 0;
                strcpy(ch, "YES");
                for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    sum = sum + pin[i][j];
                }
                if (sum != NGOOD) {
                    strcpy(ch, "NO");
                    p = 1;
                }
                printf("ROW %d %s\n", i + 1, ch);
            }
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                sum = 0;
                strcpy(ch, "YES");
                for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    sum = sum + pin[i][j];
                }
                if (sum != NGOOD) {
                    strcpy(ch, "NO");
                    p = 1;
                }
                printf("COLUMN %d %s\n", j + 1, ch);
            }
            sum = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                sum = sum + pin[i][i];
                sum2 = sum2 + pin[N - 1 - i][i];
            }
            if (sum != NGOOD) {
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
                p = 1;
            }
            printf("DIAG1 %s\n", ch);
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            if (sum2 != NGOOD) {
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
                p = 1;
            }
            printf("DIAG2 %s\n", ch);
            printf("UNIQUE %s\n", unique);
            strcpy(ch, "YES");
            if (p == 1) {
                strcpy(ch, "NO");
            }
            printf("MAGIC %s\n", ch);
        }

        else if (strcmp("-create", argv[1]) == 0) {
            int N = atoi(argv[2]);
#if 0
            int pin[MAXN][MAXN];
#endif
            int row = N - 1;
            int col = N / 2;

            for (int i = 1; i <= N * N; i++) {
                int tempr = row;
                int tempc = col;

                pin[row][col] = i;
                row++;
                col++;
                if (row == N) {
                    row = 0;
                }
                if (col == N) {
                    col = 0;
                }
                if ((pin[row][col] >= 1) & (pin[row][col] <= N * N)) {
                    row = tempr - 1;
                    col = tempc;
                }
            }
            printf("%d\n", N);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", pin[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Such action cannot be done");
        }
    }
    else if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("At least one argument expected.\n");
    }

#if 1
    fclose(fin);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the program output for your posted "big" input:

```
ROW 1 YES
ROW 2 YES
ROW 3 YES
ROW 4 YES
ROW 5 YES
ROW 6 YES
ROW 7 YES
ROW 8 YES
ROW 9 YES
ROW 10 YES
ROW 11 YES
ROW 12 YES
ROW 13 YES
ROW 14 YES
ROW 15 YES
ROW 16 YES
ROW 17 YES
ROW 18 YES
ROW 19 YES
ROW 20 YES
ROW 21 YES
ROW 22 YES
ROW 23 YES
ROW 24 YES
ROW 25 YES
ROW 26 YES
ROW 27 YES
ROW 28 YES
ROW 29 YES
ROW 30 YES
ROW 31 YES
ROW 32 YES
ROW 33 YES
ROW 34 YES
ROW 35 YES
ROW 36 YES
ROW 37 YES
COLUMN 1 YES
COLUMN 2 YES
COLUMN 3 YES
COLUMN 4 YES
COLUMN 5 YES
COLUMN 6 YES
COLUMN 7 YES
COLUMN 8 YES
COLUMN 9 YES
COLUMN 10 YES
COLUMN 11 YES
COLUMN 12 YES
COLUMN 13 YES
COLUMN 14 YES
COLUMN 15 YES
COLUMN 16 YES
COLUMN 17 YES
COLUMN 18 YES
COLUMN 19 YES
COLUMN 20 YES
COLUMN 21 YES
COLUMN 22 YES
COLUMN 23 YES
COLUMN 24 YES
COLUMN 25 YES
COLUMN 26 YES
COLUMN 27 YES
COLUMN 28 YES
COLUMN 29 YES
COLUMN 30 YES
COLUMN 31 YES
COLUMN 32 YES
COLUMN 33 YES
COLUMN 34 YES
COLUMN 35 YES
COLUMN 36 YES
COLUMN 37 YES
DIAG1 YES
DIAG2 YES
UNIQUE YES
MAGIC YES
```